# Circumvent eslint rule 'no-unused-vars' without disabling it

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm trying to create an instance of a class, this class only sets up listeners but there is no need to call any methods manually in the class.

Below is the module I load in my html file, I create a simple MVC-Pattern but I get an eslint error on line 4.
I need the constructor of the class GameController to run in order to setup the listeners but for that I need an instance of it.

I've tried making a dummy function in the GameController class and calling that. Gets rid of the error but obviously that's not the way to go, I'm looking for a clean alternative.

```
function init() {
  let data = new GameData(),
    view = new GameView(data),
    controller = new GameController(data, view);

}

init();
```

```
class GameController {
  constructor(data, view) {
    this.data = data;
    this.view = view;
    this.letterGenerator = LetterGenerator();

    this.view.addEventListener(Config.EVENT.CONSONANT, this.onConsonantClicked
      .bind(this));
    this.view.addEventListener(Config.EVENT.VOWEL, this.onVowelClicked.bind(
      this));
    this.view.addEventListener(Config.EVENT.STOP, this.onGameEnd.bind(this));
  }

  onVowelClicked() {
    ...
  }

  onConsonantClicked() {
    ...
  }

  onGameEnd(event) {
    ...
  }
}
```

What I want is instantiate a GameController but not use it, eslint basically forces me to make a dummy function in the GameController class that I need to call to get rid of the error.

Comment: Just remove the variables in `init()`? Also, having instances that are not needed seems incorrect.

Comment: You mean just writing new GameController() instead of controller = new GameController() ?

That jsut gives another eslint error.

Comment: Well, you never use the `controller` variable, so just having `new GameController(data, view)` as a stand-alone statement would do the same.

Comment: Doing that gives the eslint error "no-new"

Comment: Well, in that case you should either reconsider your rules or your architecture. A class that is instantiate then discarded immediately, and only serves to call a few things here and there in the constructor seems wrong. ESLint seems to agree.

Comment: I agree with @VLAZ. It seems like you aren't using classes as they are meant to be used. Instead, I would change your `GameController` class to a function and then call that function to setup your event listeners.